# Wordpress how to override function get_order_report_data from wc_admin_report

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, status

I want to change a part of the `get_order_report_data()` function inside `class-wc-admin-report.php` without touching the core.

I would like to change the order status filter, right now it is:

```
$query['where']  = "
            WHERE   posts.post_type     = 'shop_order'
            AND     posts.post_status   = 'publish'
            AND     tax.taxonomy        = 'shop_order_status'
            AND     term.slug           IN ('" . implode( "','", apply_filters( 'woocommerce_reports_order_statuses', array( 'completed', 'processing', 'on-hold' ) ) ) . "')
            ";
```

And I want to change the *term.slug* to `custom_status`.

I don't now how to do this with a plugin or something like that

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This question seems a bit muddled, but here is my best interpretation.

If you want to add a custom status to capture in the query write a filter function like this:

```
function woocommerce_reports_order_statuses_filter( $order_status ){
    $order_status[] = 'custom_status';
    return $order_status;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_reports_order_statuses', 'woocommerce_reports_order_statuses_filter' );
```

Later on in the function all the statuses in that array get 'wc-' appended to their values for the actual query string. So you'll need your status to have that prefix. Or... you can modify the querystring with a later filter:

```
function woocommerce_reports_get_order_report_query_filter( $query ){
    $custom_status = 'custom_status';
    $query['where'] = substr_replace( $query['where'], $custom_status , strpos( $query['where'], 'wc-' . $custom_status), strlen('wc-' . $custom_status)  );
    return $query;
}
add_filter( 'woocommerce_reports_get_order_report_query', 'woocommerce_reports_get_order_report_query_filter' );
```

All this filter code gets added to your theme `functions.php` or custom plugin code.

Answer (score 1):

Filters are applied here, which will allow you to alter `term.slug` however you'd like.

In a custom plugin (or *functions.php* of your theme), add a filter:

```
function override_order_report_data_terms($slug_array) {
    return array('custom_status');
}
add_filter('woocommerce_reports_order_statuses', 'override_order_report_data_terms');
```

Read more about [`add_filter()` in the Codex](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/add_filter).

Comment: I couldn't find a filter called 'get_order_report_data'. Am I missing something?

Comment: @JamesJones ... I have no idea where that came from. It should have been the filter from the OP's question.

Comment: Oh, of course. Haha I wouldn't trust OP's question. They seem the ravings of a madman.